# android: simultaneously scrolling horizontal listView

Tags: android, layout

Consider I have two Horizontal ListView as shown below:

---

### list1

---

### list2

I want to know if it is possible to make the second list (list2) view scroll horizontally simultaneously along with the scroll of first list (list1).....

That is when I scroll list1 (horizontal), even list2 must scroll by the same offset...

Is this possible, if yes, please do help...

![link to image]: https://picasaweb.google.com/109389839906668906213/January132012#5697019272538269218

Comment: How are you implementing it?? Horizontal list views are not there in android.
Are you using HorizontalScrollView or your some custom Listview?
If both the lists should scroll with the same offset simultanously irrespective of whether user is scrolling list1 or list2, 
why dont you make this as a combined list i.e the list element view in a way that it looks like as two rows.

Comment: Well i'll just put up the snap shot so that u'l have a clear idea..

Comment: ya akkilis there's the link.. hope u understood what i'm asking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As There is no HorizontalListView in Android, you must having another adapter view, anyway implement following:

```
list1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
{
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView adapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id){
       list2.setSelection(position);
   }
});
```

Comment: HorizontalScrollView is provided in Android, HorizontalListViews are not there. You might need to edit your post

Comment: sorry, it was HorizontalListView I was referring I has edited my post accordingly.

Comment: This answer is not working, the second ListView isn't scrolling

Answer (score 2):

You can do that - just create such layout and use scroll events:

```
list1.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    list2.setSelectionFromTop(firstVisibleItem, list1.getChildAt(0).getTop());
                }
            });
```

Some explanation:

Better use `list.setSelectionFromTop()` than `list.scrollTo()` - because first visible item of first list can be shown partially.

`list1.getChildAt(0).getTop()` - is construction for getting value of X coordinate of first visible item.

Comment: @Jin35:can u send me the method declaration for setselectionFromTop,becuase i dont have this method in my downlaoded one.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/widget/ListView.java#ListView.setSelectionFromTop%28int%2Cint%29

Comment: @Jin35:whether u added that coding into the horizontal list view class.?

Comment: This answer is good for `ListView`, but not so good for `HorizontalScrollView`, which extends `AbstractView` rather than `AbsListView`.